# AWS EKS OIDC Authenticator returns 403 when attempting to initialise

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, keycloak, openid-connect, amazon-eks

I am looking to try and integrate Keycloak with EKS as the OIDC provider and whilst I have been successful in the past, I am struggling at the moment with a new configuration and I am not really sure of the issue.

I have followed all the various guides - in particular this [one](https://epam.github.io/edp-install/operator-guide/configure-keycloak-oidc-eks/) and have a very similar configuration. However whilst the token is retrieved during the kubectl login process (from the local machine), it appears that when it is sent to the the EKS API, it is unable to hit the Keycloak endpoint.

There are two errors that I can see, the first which is pretty consistent is:

[EKS OIDC Authenticator Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KBEF.png)

```
oidc authenticator: initializing plugin: 403 Forbidden: <html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

And the second is:

[kubectl login error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NY2P5.png)

`"Unable to authenticate the request" err="[invalid bearer token, oidc: authenticator not initialized, unknown]"`

It is worth noting that we are running:

- EKS v1.28 in private endpoint mode only
- Keycloak v 20.0.2

We are running Keycloak within a Pod in that EKS Cluster and are using a number of load balancers (behind an nginx server) to route the traffic publicly back to the pod. Having tested this we can hit:

https://keycloak.example.com/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration

externally and it gives the required config.

All I can see is that for some reason the OIDC Authenticator process cannot pull down the config and therefore cannot validate the token - however it is not clear why. The nginx server and the outbound firewall both do not seem to see the 'configuration' request. Our original thought is that there was a 403 coming from the nginx server, but we cannot see anything in the access logs...

Is this related to this being a 'private' endpoint only configuration? Is the control plane able to make outbound requests to the keycloak endpoint when it is fully private? Where is the 403 coming from...?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!